# Prove the conditions are not possible for the two linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^{14} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^{10} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{14}$ and $g\circ f\equiv0$, $f$ is injective and $g$ is onto.

> Prove the above conditions are a contradiction.

Well, I do know by the dimensions theorem (If I'm not mistaken):
$\dim Ker(f)=0$ (because $f$ is injective). Therefore, $\dim Im(f)=10$.
$\dim Im(g)=5$ (because $g$ is onto). Therefore, $\dim Ker(g)=9$ (?)

How to proceed?

Comment: Notice that in the composition, the image of $g$ becomes the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this result
$$g\circ f=0\iff \operatorname{im} f\subset \ker g$$
to find a contradiction.

Comment: is it right that $\dim ker(g)=9$?

Comment: Yes right since $g$ is onto so $\operatorname{im} g=\Bbb R^5$ and the rank nullity theorem gives the result.

Comment: Wait a minute, is it even right to composite $f\circ g$?

Comment: Surely you have a typo: $f\circ g$ doesn't make sense!

Comment: OK, I wrote it down and got it. Cheers!

Comment: you're welcome.